# Strict Ordering with Multiplication on Natural Numbers

Tags: natural-numbers

I'm trying to prove that for all $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{N}$ we have that
\begin{align*}\tag{*}
(a<b)\wedge (c<d)\Longrightarrow a \cdot c < b\cdot d.
\end{align*}

I know that for all $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{N}$ we have that
\begin{align*}\tag{**}
(a\leq b)\wedge (c\leq d)\Longrightarrow a\cdot c \leq b\cdot d
\end{align*}
and, for $c\neq 0$, we also have
\begin{align*}\tag{***}
a<b \Longleftrightarrow a\cdot c < b\cdot c.
\end{align*}

Using $(***)$ we can show that $(*)$ holds for $b\neq 0$ and $c\neq 0$. But how can we prove that $(*)$ holds for all $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{N}$? Using $(**)$ we can show that $a\cdot c \leq b\cdot d$ for all $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{N}$. But in order for $(*)$ to hold, we then have to show that $a\cdot c \neq b\cdot d$. Anyone got an idea?

Comment: Well, you just have to see what happens in the cases where $b=0$ or $c=0$.

Comment: yep, that did the job. thanks

Answer (score 1):

$$ bd - ac = bd - ad + ad - ac = (b-a)d  + a (d-c)   $$

from your conditions, $b-a, d, a, d-c$  are all positive, the two products  are positive, and the sum of those is positive. So $bd - ac >0$